# renameTo() not working

Tags: java, groovy

I need to rename a file by replacing `-` with `_` in the file name.

Suppose if a file name is `ab-9.xml`, it should be `ab_9.xml`.

`renameTo()` is not working for me. Is there any other way to do that? Here is my code:

```
File replaceCheracter(File file) {
        File oldPath = new File(file.getPath())
        String filePath = file.getPath()
        if(filePath.contains("-")){
            String newFilePath = filePath.replace("-", "_")
            if(oldPath.renameTo(newFilePath)) {
                System.out.println("renamed");
             } else {
                System.out.println("Error");
             }
        }
        return oldPath
    }
```

Comment: how "deep" is the path there?  more than one?

Comment: Did you try this: filePath.replaceAll("-", "_")

Comment: `assert new File("captain.txt").renameTo("u_wot_m8.txt")` worked fine here, but i'm on linux. Are you on windows? I recall being bitten by some file-renaming-OS-discrepancy on *nix->windows transition some months ago.

Comment: Basic debugging info would show you tried solving it by yourself (and possibly help others to solve it) - that is, what is `oldPath.getPath()` before and after rename, and how did `newFilePath` turn out.

Comment: I believe `renameTo` requires a `File` as a parameter, like so: `oldPath.renameTo(new File(newFilePath))`

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using the [java.nio.file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package:

```
final Path file = Paths.get("path\\to\\your-file.txt");

Files.move(file, file.resolveSibling(file.getFileName().toString().replace("-", "_")));
```

Used the very handy function [Path#resolveSibling()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolveSibling-java.lang.String-) as second argument for [Files#move()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).

Explanation:

- `Path#resolveSibling()` takes the directory path of the `Path` object it is called on, and swaps the last part (the actual *file name*) for the supplied argument (the new, modified file name in this case).

Using this behavior as second argument for `Files#move()` will result in a move where the source directory and the target directory are the same, thus it only renames the file.

See [The Java Tutorials - File I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) for further information on this.

Answer (score 0):

`renameTo` method accepts File as parameter not String

Change `oldPath.renameTo(newFilePath)` with 
`oldPath.renameTo(new File(newFilePath))`

Comment: But it does in groovy